# How can a function return if a number is a factor of another?

Tags: function, math, numbers, boolean, factoring

I'm writing a function for Python 3.7.3 that tests if a number is a factor of another number.

I tried researching on the internet to find some idea about how the write a function that tests the validity of factoring two unknown real numbers. I ended up stumbling upon the difference between factoring and divisibility, which intrigued me somewhat.

```
def is_factor(f, n):
    """This function returns if f, a real number, is a factor of another
    real number n."""
    while f * f <= n:
        if f % n == 0:          
            f /= n
            #return True?
        else: f += 1 #return False?

print(is_factor(1, 15))
```

The function appears to work, because Python returns None, and that's all. I expect the function to return a True or False solution. There must be some logical error in the code. Any feed back is appreciated.

Comment: Where do you expect a true or false value to be returned from your function?

Comment: Would you mind adding a bit of explanation regarding your code draft? Besides the fact that there is no place where it returns True or False, I can't seem to see the mathematical reasoning behind it.

Comment: Every non-zero real number is a factor of every other real number, there is no other obstacle to division in the real numbers. Why did you copy paste a (part of a) factorization algorithm (finding all prime factors) when you want something much simpler?

Comment: Perhaps you forgot to do something [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56159486/)

Comment: It is worth to describe real problem that motivated you to make `is_factor`

Answer (score 2):

If you are dealing with integers, use:

```
def is_factor(f, n):
    return n%f==0
```

If you are dealing with real numbers, the above code works but is very sensitive to floating point imprecision. Instead, you can divide `n` by `f` and see if you get back `n` after rounding to the nearest integer:

```
def is_factor(f, n, e):
    return abs(round(n/f)*f-n)<e
```

Comment: Thank you for providing a quick solution for my function. I could've have worded it differently, although both of your answers are noteworthy, because they raise intelligent implications. Regarding other replies: the problem is deliberately abstract, so there isn't a clear solution.

Comment: @NationalRex22 I'm not sure I understand your comment. What would you have done differently? And regarding "the problem is deliberately abstract, so there isn't a clear solution": The question is quite clear and concrete to me: You ask how you can code a function that returns True when a number `f` is a factor of a number `n` and False otherwise. There is a clear solution to that question.